# Using Snowflake SQL how do you find two records and then change another one based on those records to a predefined record using a local variable?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using SQL how do you use two records to find a place, hold onto that place and use that record to replace 'Nonsense' value with that held onto place? I am going to show what I have been able to write so far, but then write out what I am still trying to figure out:

```
SELECT * FROM "TABLES". "ACCTS_OF_SUPERHEROS".;

DECLARE @count_rows INT = 0;
DECLARE @row_total INT = 0;
DECLARE @refAcctNum INT = 0;
DECLARE @selectedPlaceName TINYTEXT;

SET @row_total = SELECT COUNT (*)

WHILE countRows < row_total
    for each acct_num store value in refAcctNum. 
    Using refAcctNum find place: "Gotham City", "Central City", "Metropolis", "Smallville", "Star City", "Fawcett City" store that in selectedPlaceName.
    If refAccountNumber has Nonsense then replace with selectedPlaceName record
    otherwise add + 1 to countRows and repeat. 
END
```

**Current table data; "ACCTS_OF_SUPERHEROS" table**:

```
| row | acct_num | exact_address    | place
| --- | -------- |------------------|--------
| 1   | 049403   | 344 Clinton Str  | Metropolis 
| 2   | 049403   | 344 Clinton Str  | Nonsense
| 3   | 049206   | 1007 Mountain Dr | Gotham City
| 4   | 049206   | 1007 Mountain Dr | Gotham City
| 5   | 049206   | 1096 Show Dr.    | Fawcett City
| 6   | 049206   | 1096 Show Dr.    | Nonsense
| 7   | 049206   | NULL             | Nonsense
| 8   | 049291   | 1938 Sullivan Pl | Smallville
| 9   | 049293   | 700 Hamilton Str | Central City
| 10  | 049396   | 800 Nonsense Way | Nonsense
| 11  | 049396   | NULL             | Nonsense
```

**Desired output**:

```
| row | acct_num | exact_address    | place
| --- | -------- |------------------|--------
| 1   | 049403   | 344 Clinton Str  | Metropolis 
| 2   | 049403   | 344 Clinton Str  | Metropolis
| 3   | 049206   | 1007 Mountain Dr | Gotham City
| 4   | 049206   | 1007 Mountain Dr | Gotham City
| 5   | 049206   | 1096 Show Dr.    | Fawcett City
| 6   | 049206   | 1096 Show Dr.    | Fawcett City
| 7   | 049206   | NULL             | Fawcett City
| 8   | 049291   | 1938 Sullivan Pl | Smallville
| 9   | 049293   | 700 Hamilton Str | Central City
| 10  | 049396   | 800 Tidal Way    | Star City
| 11  | 049396   | NULL             | Star City
```

Comment: How does the last row get "Star City"?

Comment: Great question, we know based on the exact address - I know this will be very hard to program, but the scenario is possible I just want to know if anyone has dealt with this type of issue before.

Comment: Can an acct_number have more than one place associated with it? (other than Nonsense) If so, which value should take place of Nonsense?

Comment: @PhilCoulson No, the acct_num should always be associated with the exact_address and the place that acct_num has already been associated with, but nonsense has to be replaced with that place

Comment: @MatthewMcNey That's what I am asking. Can it be only associated with only one place and address?

Comment: @PhilCoulson There could be multiple exact_address associated with the same place, but acct_num and place are absolutely linked - so it is just a matter of finding the place associated with the acct_num and then changing the Nonsense to that place

Comment: @MatthewMcNey In that case, what is wrong with Gordon's solution? Seems perfectly fine to me. It only returns null if you don't have any place associated with an acct_num(other than Nonsense). You can always filter those out or use `coalesce` to replace it with something else if you wish to, I would think null would the desired value

Comment: @PhilCoulson I was wrong. When I used Gordon's solution I discovered that the exact_address is not directly linked with the acct_num and in fact at times there is a NULL value for exact_address, what would you suggest in this case? I have updated the question and table so you can see what I am talking about

Comment: The  `max` in that solution takes care of the nulls so I don't see how that's a problem. The only edge case Gordon's solution doesn't handle is the 'Star City', which makes sense because you didn't provide the underlying logic.  For everything else, it seems to work as expected

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pu1PkjzKCM9VRciznkJc4L/1

Comment: @PhilCoulson I updated the table with the data points that break Gordon's solution. I did not know the acct_num had more than one exact_address when I wrote the original question and this will break his solution - my apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when place <> 'Nonsense' then place end) over (partition by acct_num) as imputed_place
from t;
```

This returns `NULL` if all the rows are `'Nonsense'` for a given `acct_num`.  You can use `COALESCE()` to replace the value with something else.

Comment: not sure that's what I am looking for, my goal isn't to change the 'Nonsense' values to 'NULL', but to the place already associated with that acct_num and exact_address like my desired output

Comment: The `max` takes care of converting the null to the right place. It should work as expected.

Comment: OK, so I implemented @Gordon solution, but it failed to get the desired output. The issue I think is that the place and exact_address are linked. Nonsense has to be changed to the place that corresponds to that exact_address AND acct_num, I think

Comment: 'select t.*,
       max(case when place <> 'Nonsense' then place end) over (partition by  exact_address || acct_num) as imputed_place
from t;' I used the || clause to find the exact_address first then if it hits NULL use the acct_num, unfortunately, it's not replacing it with the right place name, but a random one and I am not sure where it is coming from. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MatthewMcNey Snowflake returns null for `||` or `concat` if any of the values are null. Try `select t.*, max(case when place <> 'Nonsense' then place end) over (partition by acct_num, coalesce(exact_address,acct_num) as imputed_place from t;`. If that doesn't work, I would ask a new question and include a sample dataset that is more representative of your problem than what you provided in the answer.

Comment: @MatthewMcNey . . . That code is not the code in this answer.  Your question makes it pretty clear that the `partition by` key should only be `acct_num`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated the question and the table with new information. I agree your program would work if that was the constraint, I ran it and found that your solution broke when you have more than one exact_address under an acct_num; the other issue is the fact that it will return a NULL (in the case of my actual dataset a random record) when there is no place name associated with an acct_num - one fix is to categorize the place based on the exact_address, but that still leaves the records without exact_address or an associated place that will return a NULL record

Answer (score 0):

I was reading through the available list of window functions in Snowflake and think you're going to need a new window function for this. Perhaps someone can find a more built-in way, but anyway here's a user defined table function REPLACE_WITH_LKG implemented as a window function that will replace a bad value with the last known good value. As long as I was going to write it, I thought it may as well be general purpose, so it matches "bad" values using a regular expression and JavaScript RegExp options.

```
create or replace function REPLACE_WITH_LKG("VALUE" string, "REGEXP" string, "REGEXP_OPTIONS" string)
returns table(LKG_VALUE string)
language javascript
strict immutable
as
$$
{
    initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {
        this.lkg = "";
    },
    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
        const rx = new RegExp(row.REGEXP, row.REGEXP_OPTIONS);
        if (!rx.test(row.VALUE)) {
            this.lkg = row.VALUE;
        }
        rowWriter.writeRow({LKG_VALUE: this.lkg});
    },
    finalize: function (rowWriter, context) {},
}
$$;

select S.*, LKG.LKG_VALUE as PLACE
from superhero S, table(REPLACE_WITH_LKG(PLACE, 'Nonsense', 'ig')
over(partition by null order by "ROW")) LKG;
;
```

A note on performance; the way the data shows this the're no partition other than the entire table. That's because the one obvious place to partition, by account, won't work. Row 10 is getting its value from what would be a different window if using account, so the way the sample data appears it needs to be a window that spans the entire table. This will not parallelize well and should be avoided for very large tables.